# trigonometric presentation inside a diagonal matrix.

Tags: matrices, trigonometry

How can I write an example of $2\times2$ matrix where $d_2$ belongs to the first quadrant and $d_1$ belongs to fourth quadrant, that has this form:

$D = \pmatrix{d_1&0\\0&d_2},$

I wrote something like this, and for some reason it is wrong:

$D =\pmatrix{rcis(\frac74)\pi&0\\0&rcis(\frac13)\pi}$

the university's site says that my choice of d1 is wrong. but why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first quadrant is the set of angles between $0$ and $\pi/2$.  The fourth quadrant is the set of angles between $3 \pi/2$ and $2 \pi$.  If you switch the values of $d_1$ and $d_2$, you should have a valid solution.

Comment: why? but I chose  $\pi/3$ for first quadrant and $7\pi/4$ for forth quadrant and they are inside the ranges that u wrote.

Comment: Oh, you're right. It's strange that you mentioned $d_2$ first.

Comment: Did you set a value for $r$ (such as $r = 1$), or did you write it in as "r"?